# Dynamically adapting caches to available memory

Tags: windows, linux, caching, memory-management

Is there a way to implement dynamically adapting caches in userspace? I would like my programs to allocate caches that employ some fair share of the available physical memory. If the system is running out of physical memory, caches should be dropped as chosen by the program, and in no case should they be swapped out. It is preferrable that no special privilege was needed, so it is not necessary to actually lock the memory. The program should just get to know that pages are swapped out, so it is not going to use them. All in all, it should work something like caches and buffers implemented in the kernel. Can you point out general ideas and APIs how that can be done? Platforms I am interested in are Linux and Windows.

Comment: Which kind of caches are you talking about? The processor caches??? The file system cache???

Comment: The kernel file system cache is the counterpart I am referring to. Basically, what I am caching is potentially large indexes and other previously computed results, something that can be reconstructed if needed but should be kept in memory if it is available.

Comment: With Linux there are some syscalls to tune the file cache (`readahead(2)` `madvise(2)` ...). And Gnu/Hurd has external pagers.

Comment: Ok, mincore(2) can solve the part of avoiding swapped-out pages. Then there is the problem of determining the amount of virtual memory to allocate. That can be limited to some portion of the available physical memory, which can be polled occasionally. I think these can be worked to a satisfactory solution. Are there counterparts for these in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think there is any reasonable way to define "fair share"?  It's not really a great UX when the application tries to know too much: far better would be to find a sensible, **minimal** default, and offer the user a config option to adjust it.  Even better is to provide the user with stats to show how well the current-sized cache is doing - bigger isn't always better.

There is no "cooperative memory management" API in Linux - no way for the kernel to tell user-space to use less memory.  The closest I can think of is that the (relatively new) memory cgroup controller can provide a "notifier" when a memory limit is reached (rather than OOM-killing the allocating process.)  That's not exactly nice to use, but then again, any such interface is going to flirt with being race/deadlock-prone.  Polling with mincore might work in somewhat contrived/constrained situations, but given that the app has no way to understand the changing system-wide demand for memory, it's not going to work well.